# Moving legend outside pgfplot and reformat x axis labels in tikz

Tags: latex, tikz

I've made a schematic plot in tikz with the below code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$Treatment$,
ylabel=$Level of donation$]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,1)
    (3,1)
};
\addlegendentry{Pure Altruism}

\addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,2)
    (3,1)
};
\addlegendentry{Warm Glow}

\addplot[smooth,color=green,mark=x]
plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,3)
    (3,3)
};
\addlegendentry{Mental Accounting}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My problem is twofold. First, I want to get the legend outside the plot. Second, I want to add my own, non-numeric labels to the x axis. I want these labels to be treatment names, rather than numbers. How can I make both these adjustments?

Comment: I would post here instead: https://tex.stackexchange.com/